# How to grab the titles from these JSON results?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have this JSON:

```
{"Request":{"authentication":"true","key":{},"method":{}},"search":{"query":{},"results-start":"1","results-end":"20","total-results":"453","source":"Goodreads","query-time-seconds":"0.15","results":{"work":[{"id":"3275794","books_count":"415","ratings_count":"2789161","text_reviews_count":"61819","original_publication_year":"1960","original_publication_month":{"@attributes":{"type":"integer","nil":"true"}},"original_publication_day":{"@attributes":{"type":"integer","nil":"true"}},"average_rating":"4.24","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"2657","title":"To Kill a Mockingbird","author":{"id":"1825","name":"Harper Lee"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1361975680m\/2657.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1361975680s\/2657.jpg"}},{"id":"6790315","books_count":"21","ratings_count":"20230","text_reviews_count":"3203","original_publication_year":"2010","original_publication_month":"1","original_publication_day":"1","average_rating":"4.17","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"6596547","title":"Mockingbird","author":{"id":"688672","name":"Kathryn Erskine"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1301271068m\/6596547.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1301271068s\/6596547.jpg"}},{"id":"7100578","books_count":"8","ratings_count":"5526","text_reviews_count":"942","original_publication_year":"2010","original_publication_month":"11","original_publication_day":"2","average_rating":"3.79","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"6882274","title":"The Mockingbirds (The Mockingbirds, #1)","author":{"id":"3081700","name":"Daisy Whitney"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1281310031m\/6882274.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1281310031s\/6882274.jpg"}},{"id":"313880","books_count":"37","ratings_count":"2856","text_reviews_count":"295","original_publication_year":"1980","original_publication_month":{"@attributes":{"type":"integer","nil":"true"}},"original_publication_day":{"@attributes":{"type":"integer","nil":"true"}},"average_rating":"4.12","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"323172","title":"Mockingbird","author":{"id":"4448408","name":"Walter Tevis"},"image_url":"https:\/\/s.gr-assets.com\/assets\/nophoto\/book\/111x148-bcc042a9c91a29c1d680899eff700a03.png","small_image_url":"https:\/\/s.gr-assets.com\/assets\/nophoto\/book\/50x75-a91bf249278a81aabab721ef782c4a74.png"}},{"id":"372876","books_count":"3","ratings_count":"637","text_reviews_count":"50","original_publication_year":"1998","original_publication_month":{"@attributes":{"type":"integer","nil":"true"}},"original_publication_day":{"@attributes":{"type":"integer","nil":"true"}},"average_rating":"3.86","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"383106","title":"Mockingbird","author":{"id":"13143","name":"Sean Stewart"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1354903122m\/383106.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1354903122s\/383106.jpg"}},{"id":"21954272","books_count":"2","ratings_count":"56","text_reviews_count":"24","original_publication_year":"2013","original_publication_month":"8","original_publication_day":"13","average_rating":"3.61","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"16129330","title":"Mockingbird","author":{"id":"6572384","name":"Julie Trimingham"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1386729777m\/16129330.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1386729777s\/16129330.jpg"}},{"id":"44458285","books_count":"71","ratings_count":"104794","text_reviews_count":"18897","original_publication_year":"2015","original_publication_month":"7","original_publication_day":"14","average_rating":"3.32","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"24817626","title":"Go Set a Watchman (To Kill a Mockingbird, #2)","author":{"id":"1825","name":"Harper Lee"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1451442088m\/24817626.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1451442088s\/24817626.jpg"}},{"id":"676450","books_count":"8","ratings_count":"609","text_reviews_count":"142","original_publication_year":"2007","original_publication_month":"4","original_publication_day":"1","average_rating":"3.46","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"690102","title":"In Search of Mockingbird","author":{"id":"369002","name":"Loretta Ellsworth"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1316727230m\/690102.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1316727230s\/690102.jpg"}},{"id":"26123583","books_count":"4","ratings_count":"2541","text_reviews_count":"593","original_publication_year":"2014","original_publication_month":"5","original_publication_day":"20","average_rating":"3.79","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"18465605","title":"I Kill the Mockingbird","author":{"id":"321290","name":"Paul Acampora"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1380963917m\/18465605.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1380963917s\/18465605.jpg"}},{"id":"41055515","books_count":"1","ratings_count":"0","text_reviews_count":"0","original_publication_year":"2014","original_publication_month":"1","original_publication_day":"1","average_rating":"0.0","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"21799755","title":"Mockingbird","author":{"id":"7189690","name":"X"},"image_url":"https:\/\/s.gr-assets.com\/assets\/nophoto\/book\/111x148-bcc042a9c91a29c1d680899eff700a03.png","small_image_url":"https:\/\/s.gr-assets.com\/assets\/nophoto\/book\/50x75-a91bf249278a81aabab721ef782c4a74.png"}},{"id":"18281451","books_count":"21","ratings_count":"2406","text_reviews_count":"382","original_publication_year":"2012","original_publication_month":"1","original_publication_day":"1","average_rating":"4.13","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"13108221","title":"Mockingbird (Miriam Black, #2)","author":{"id":"17152","name":"Chuck Wendig"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1330371155m\/13108221.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1330371155s\/13108221.jpg"}},{"id":"19221873","books_count":"2","ratings_count":"1665","text_reviews_count":"238","original_publication_year":"2013","original_publication_month":"4","original_publication_day":"23","average_rating":"4.06","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"15843172","title":"Tequila Mockingbird: Cocktails with a Literary Twist","author":{"id":"5446689","name":"Tim Federle"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1359423297m\/15843172.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1359423297s\/15843172.jpg"}},{"id":"3570755","books_count":"3","ratings_count":"46","text_reviews_count":"9","original_publication_year":"1998","original_publication_month":{"@attributes":{"type":"integer","nil":"true"}},"original_publication_day":{"@attributes":{"type":"integer","nil":"true"}},"average_rating":"3.59","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"1619397","title":"Mockingbird","author":{"id":"45317","name":"Allan Ahlberg"},"image_url":"https:\/\/s.gr-assets.com\/assets\/nophoto\/book\/111x148-bcc042a9c91a29c1d680899eff700a03.png","small_image_url":"https:\/\/s.gr-assets.com\/assets\/nophoto\/book\/50x75-a91bf249278a81aabab721ef782c4a74.png"}},{"id":"15930583","books_count":"8","ratings_count":"837","text_reviews_count":"185","original_publication_year":"2012","original_publication_month":"2","original_publication_day":"6","average_rating":"3.70","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"11011545","title":"The Rivals (The Mockingbirds, #2)","author":{"id":"3081700","name":"Daisy Whitney"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1329509815m\/11011545.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1329509815s\/11011545.jpg"}},{"id":"25647256","books_count":"2","ratings_count":"197","text_reviews_count":"27","original_publication_year":"2013","original_publication_month":"2","original_publication_day":"20","average_rating":"3.73","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"18218379","title":"The Song of the Mockingbird","author":{"id":"6448032","name":"Bill Cronin"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1376853384m\/18218379.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1376853384s\/18218379.jpg"}},{"id":"808023","books_count":"13","ratings_count":"1472","text_reviews_count":"62","original_publication_year":"1972","original_publication_month":"1","original_publication_day":"1","average_rating":"4.14","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"39774","title":"Mockingbird Wish Me Luck","author":{"id":"13275","name":"Charles Bukowski"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1407706745m\/39774.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1407706745s\/39774.jpg"}},{"id":"21946472","books_count":"6","ratings_count":"974","text_reviews_count":"219","original_publication_year":"2013","original_publication_month":"6","original_publication_day":"1","average_rating":"3.77","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"16124135","title":"When Mockingbirds Sing","author":{"id":"3448642","name":"Billy Coffey"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1351878615m\/16124135.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1351878615s\/16124135.jpg"}},{"id":"45115186","books_count":"4","ratings_count":"89","text_reviews_count":"34","original_publication_year":"2015","original_publication_month":"5","original_publication_day":"7","average_rating":"4.10","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"25368964","title":"Mockingbird Songs","author":{"id":"1086719","name":"R.J. Ellory"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1429176973m\/25368964.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1429176973s\/25368964.jpg"}},{"id":"40785903","books_count":"4","ratings_count":"1576","text_reviews_count":"227","original_publication_year":"2014","original_publication_month":"6","original_publication_day":"26","average_rating":"4.27","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"21468147","title":"Tequila Mockingbird (Sinners #3)","author":{"id":"4968409","name":"Rhys Ford"},"image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1394939612m\/21468147.jpg","small_image_url":"https:\/\/d.gr-assets.com\/books\/1394939612s\/21468147.jpg"}},{"id":"20261011","books_count":"2","ratings_count":"5","text_reviews_count":"3","original_publication_year":"2009","original_publication_month":"12","original_publication_day":"7","average_rating":"4.60","best_book":{"@attributes":{"type":"Book"},"id":"12592969","title":"The Song of the Mockingbird","author":{"id":"5524594","name":"McDonald Mark McDonald"},"image_url":"https:\/\/s.gr-assets.com\/assets\/nophoto\/book\/111x148-bcc042a9c91a29c1d680899eff700a03.png","small_image_url":"https:\/\/s.gr-assets.com\/assets\/nophoto\/book\/50x75-a91bf249278a81aabab721ef782c4a74.png"}}]}}}
```

...which was created by doing a goodreads API search for the term "Mockingbird" and converting the results from XML to JSON using this script:

```
<?php 
    $xml_string = file_get_contents("https://www.goodreads.com/search?q=" .$_REQUEST['search']. "&search%5Bfield%5D=title&format=xml&key=ZuqW9sL15d3JvEwmLyaNCg");
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
    echo $json;
?>
```

My question is how to grab the titles from the JSON results. Part of the problem is that in the JSON, I believe work is an array and title is a member of best_book in the array items. So, I'm trying to implement something like:

```
$.each(json.search.results.work, function(){
    console.log(this.best_book.title);
});
```

but in doing so, I get the error "Unexpected token ." for the first line of code.

Does anyone have ideas? Thank you.

edit: Here's my AJAX call:

```
function GetBooks(request) {
    //Replace spaces with a '+'
    var url = request.term.replace(/\s/g,"+");
    return $.ajax({
        'url': "php/bookscript.php?search=" + url,
        'dataType': 'json'
    }).then(function(data){
        return $.map(data.results || [], function(v,i){
            return {
                label: 'test',
                value: 'test'
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: It's really impossible to use that single line, ten-mile-long piece of JSON that you have at the beginning there. Could you perhaps `var_dump($array);` and post the results of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so (you should change `data` to your variable):

```
$.each(data.search.results.work, function(index, value){
    console.log(value.best_book.title);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7c43bz35/

Update:

I don't really know what is label and what is value, but that should help you:

```
$.map(data.search.results.work || [], function(v, i) {
    return {
        value : v.best_book.title
    }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7c43bz35/1/

Comment: Thank you. That works great! I've been trying to get this working with my AJAX call for a while now and keep coming up short. I've edited the AJAX call into the original post now. Do you know how I'd combine your code with the call so that it returns label and value of `value.best_book.title`?

Comment: Updated my answer. If you have additional questions you should create a new question.